# Javafx: Is there a way to prevent standby in fullscreen?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm using JavaFX to write a small application to play videos. I'm on a Mac (Mac OS X 10.10.5), using Java 1.8.0_65-b17.

AFter the video is in fullscreen for a while, the machine goes to standby. Is there a way to prevent this behavior, and to have the same behavior of all the apps that go in fullscreen?

Comment: `and to have the same behavior of all the apps that go in fullscreen?` That part of the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, you might want to ask that on [Ask Different (the Apple Stack Exchange site)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I ment to have the expected behavior of all applications in all operating systems, so when they are in fullscreen the OS doesn't go in stand by or doesn't activate the screensaver, sorry English is not my native language...